# PIC32 C programming

Tags: pic, microchip

I'm getting into PIC microcontrollers and more specifically PIC32s. For all the people that program these chips, how did you learn? I've seen books to learn C programming for PICs but is it really necessary in order to learn how to program PICs?

Comment: This would work better in the EE.SE chat.  The question is opinion-based.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to program PICs in C or in Assembply Language - that is, what is your definition of "programming PICs"?

Comment: What other alternative do you see for programming embedded microcontrollers? There is only C and assembly to choose from, and C is appreciably easier to work with as a beginner.

Comment: [PIC32 Tutorials](http://umassamherstm5.org/tech-tutorials/pic32-tutorials/pic32mx220-tutorials)

Answer (score 2):

I should point out that the OP said PIC32 which, in the company of the ARM Cortex Ms, is a large 32-bit world away from the 8 bit PIC16. I'm writing assembly right now for a PIC16F1825 but I wouldn't dream of using anything but C for the PIC32 or ARM Cortex M. Optimisation routines maybe in assembly, but MIPS and ARM assembly isn't a walk in the park and that's not where I'd start.

Microchip have a free XC32 compiler (crippled for optimisation, which is actually gcc for the MIPS core found in the PIC32).

I would definately go the route of one of the PIC32MX starter kits (http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/32bit/) with a PICkit3. Install MPLABX and XC32 and see how you get on with their starter tutorials.

If there's a decent PIC32 focussed tutorial online or in a book, I'd follow it!

Answer (score 0):

The department at my school teaches almost exclusively on pics, and we start from the bottom with assembly. It's an excellent way to learn about how this particular architecture operates. That being said, it would probably be a lot more encouraging if you went the 'c' route first.

Without the structure of the classroom environment, I'd suggest finding a project that looks interesting but manageable on the net and just work at it. It will be very discouraging at first, and probably for the rest of your life. If you wanna take the easy way just get an Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

As carveone pointed alluded to the PIC and PIC32 are vastly different.  The PIC32 has a MIPS core, the other PICS have a microchip PIC core, which is a wee bitty minimalist thing.  For the PIC32 I would agree that C plus some asm is the way to go and you can use gcc or the tools from microchip, most of the learning is making api calls or writing to registers, little to do with the core processor.  For the non PIC32, PICs I personally would not go near C for those, the are very C unfriendly designs, are extremely resource limited (ram/rom) so I would go with ASM which is pretty easy to learn.

Embedded is embedded the learning curve has to do with mastering the toolchains and debuggging with little more than a blinking led or if lucky a uart, even better an oscilloscope.  Some assembly is required, reading of schematics is required, occasionally damaging hardware will happen, so buy spares.  Reading often poorly written manuals (Microchip is particularly bad) to figure out how to use the peripherals is where most of the time is spent with this kind of work.

I recommend starting with simulators, they can have better visibility into the processor than a real chip where you cant see anything.  Starting on hardware has a significantly higher failure rate.  The non-pic32 pics are so simple you can easily write your own simulator, if you cant bang out a pic12 or 14 or 16 simulator out, then you cant really work at this level yet as managing bits in registers, etc is what is needed for programming peripherals, etc.

When ready get a board, with an led, learn to blink it using a timing loop then learn to use the timer peripheral to measure more accurate time.  Long periods of time like seconds or tens of seconds (often the timer cant do that in one measurement so you have to measure a smaller period many times), compare the blink rate to a stopwatch or something with a second hand, when you think it should be 60 seconds is it 60 or 59 or 61 and if so why, is it the accuracy of the clock or should you have programmed N-1 instead of N into the timer, is it 30 instead of 60 because you didnt realize there was a divide by 2 going on somewhere.

Comment: You are incorrect about many modern pics.  The enhanced 12F and 16F, all 18F and all 24F have cores which are designed for an embedded C compiler.

Comment: I don't think PICS are C-friendly, but C is much easier to support IMO.

Comment: Check the family reference manuals or "[Introducing the enhanced mid-range architecture](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/SiteComm_sg/documents/DeviceDoc/en542713.pdf)".  Many modern enhanced/18F/24F PICs have instructions and optimisations designed for a C compiler.  They will never be the same as a 32-bit RISC processor, but it is incorrect to say they are not "C-friendly".